# Image taking long time to load in iphone than simulator

Tags: iphone, swift, ios-simulator

I have a collection view in view controller 1 and i want to pass the image to next view controller in a scroll view.The image is getting loaded using this code

```
 let image = selectedimage

 let smoothLinesImage = image

   imageSize = smoothLinesImage?.size

  imageScale = smoothLinesImage?.scale

 let transparencyTolerance = 90

 drawingView.loadImage(smoothLinesImage!, savedImage: selectedimage, transparencyTolerance: transparencyTolerance)
```

This selectedimage has been passed from the view controller 1 using segue.
This image is getting loaded faster in xcode simulator whereas it is taking more time to be loaded in iphone.It takes almost 10 secs to load in iphone whereas it takes less than 3 secs in xcode simulator.Could anyone tell me what could be the reason for it?

Comment: What kind of image is this? Are you downloading it, or is it in your assets?

Comment: its a png image of 1500*1500 pixels .I am downloading from api as well as using the image from assets.

Answer (score 0):

Simulator is faster than most iOS Devices since it's running on a faster CPU. So that behavior is to be expected. However, if it's taking more time to load than you want, there's something going wrong with your code.

I'd check if your image is too large, or if there's some method making it larger than expected.

Note: Simulator is usually faster on CPU and Storage tasks, GPU tasks should be faster on the physical device.